# Preventing AuthenticationState from removing claims added to ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on a Blazor Server application that uses Window Authentication through IIS and I'm having issues with updating the current Claims Principal with custom claims. Once the app has authenticated the user I have planned to use the authentication information to check against Active Directory and assign claims based on their AD Group Memberships.

I set up an IClaimsTransformation Service and while the TransformAsync Task is called successfully, each time it is called the ClaimsPrincipal has been reverted back to the original WindowsIdentity and any changes are lost. As long as everything is reapplied the claims do work after the last time transformAsync runs but I would like to see if there is a way to persist the changes to avoid the need to constantly reauthorize or manage a separate user object to store .

I have tried the following

- Setting the service as both a scoped and a singleton
- Modifying the WindowIdentity provided with the initial authentication
- adding an additional claims identity to the ClaimsPrincipal
- adding Claims as CI.CustomRoleType as well as just setting the Type and Value

My IClaimsTransormation Class:

```
public class UserAuthorizationService : IClaimsTransformation {

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public UserAuthorizationService(IConfiguration configuration) {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal) {
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();

        if (!principal.HasClaim("TestClaim", "Test")) {
            Claim customClaim = new Claim("TestClaim", "Test");
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(customClaim);
        }

        principal.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);

        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

Related Startup class configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });
    services.AddAuthorization(config => {
            config.AddPolicy("TestPolicy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("TestClaim", "Test"));
        });
    services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, UserAuthorizationService>();
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseAuthorization();
 }
```